# onmouseover function does not work inside domready event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply some javascript code in an external website code editor. I am calling a simple `onmouseover` function from a div to give an alert but it does not work here is the code: error: `ReferenceError: clickme is not defined`

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEvent('domready', function(){
            try {
                function clickme(){alert('?');}
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('ERR: '+e)
            }
        })
    </script>
```

```html
<div onmouseover="clickme()">Click me</div>
```

I have to use `document.addEvent('domready', function(){`.
Does anyone has any solution how can i use a function inside `try-catch` and `document.addEvent('domready', function()`?

Comment: `addEventListener` ?

Comment: can you give me the code?

Comment: you can use DOMContentLoaded instead of  domready

Comment: i have to use  domready because i can't change it as its in external website code editor.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this is by using a listener, you would need to be able to edit the HTML though:

HTML:

```
<div id="clickMePls">Click me</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("clickMePls").addEventListener("mouseover", clickMeFunction);

function clickMeFunction() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f1mtoby/1/).

Comment: @Hasan, yikes, sorry about that, missed the part past the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**Example Using *Mootools***

```js
// 1st way of defining clickme before "domReady"
// var clickme; 
// 2nd way of defining clickme before "domReady"
 document.addEvent('load', function(){ 
          var clickme;
        });
 document.addEvent('domready', function(){
                try {
                    clickme = function(){alert('?');}
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log('ERR: '+e)
                }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.min.js"></script>
<div onmouseover="clickme()">Click me</div>
```

**Example *no-Framework***

*With some help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the) you can define clickme the first place then bind it to a function when domready.*

```js
var clickme;
(function() {
            try {
                clickme = function(){alert('?');}
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('ERR: '+e)
            }
})();
```

```html
<div onmouseover="clickme()">Click me</div>
```

**Example Using *jQuery***

```js
var clickme;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            try {
              clickme = function(){alert('?');}
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('ERR: '+e)
            }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onmouseover="clickme()">Click me</div>
```

Comment: i can't change document.addEvent('domready', function(){  because its in external code editor. and i need an onclick/onousehover function to work

Comment: @Hasan do take alook at both examples please i think the first one is what you want.

Comment: please check here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t655r38b6uwu89j/rough?dl=0  i placed both of your code in 2 files

Comment: can you check this: http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Utilities/DOMReady

here is the domready function, and i checked no function calling works inside this domready?

Comment: @Hasan my 1st answer involves no-framework (jQuery,mootools) my second answer involves jQuery but you want an answer for mootools?? Where is the tag for this? Your question's tags are jQuery javascript. Try the 1st example as it is. In the beginning you simply have to define clickme as a var. Then you bind clickme with the function you want.

Comment: It does not work! 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            var clickme;
            (function() {
                try {
                    clickme = function(){alert('?');}
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log('ERR: '+e)
                }
            })();
        });
    </script>
<div onmouseover="clickme()">Click me</div>

Comment: @Hasan sorry i did not explain correctly maybe, you don't need to wrap the code from the example inside window.addEvent(domready... just the code in the snippet will work.

Comment: yes thats the problem, i already mentioned "i can't change document.addEvent('domready', function(){ because its a code editor is in external website. whatever JS code i write that goes inside domready document.addEvent('domready', function(){ ..............}

Comment: @Hasan your main problem as you have explained is that you can't write any js before `document.addEvent('load', function(){`, sad but true is the fact you have to find a way to override this and simply place `var clickme;` before it. Or you can place it inside `document.addEvent('load', function(){` if you are given this option, just as in the example in mootools